# Showing $T$ is $\omega$-categorical if theory of expansion is $\omega$-categorical?

Tags: model-theory

Given a countable complete theory $T$, a model $\mathcal M$, and a finite subset $A\subset M$, let $T_A$ be the complete theory of the expansion $\mathcal M_A$ to the language $\mathcal L(A)$.

Assuming $T_A$ is $\omega$-categorical, I want to show that $T$ is also $\omega$-categorical.

In the other direction I did this by showing $p\mapsto\{\phi(\bar{x},\bar{y}):\phi(\bar{x},A)\in p\}$ is an injective map from $S_n(A)\to S_{n+m}(\varnothing)$, then applying Ryll-Nardzewski.

In this direction I am trying to use Ryll-Nardzewski again but I haven't been able to find a map from $S_n(\varnothing)\to S_m(A)$ for $n\leq m$ to bound the cardinality.
I've also tried using $f:p\mapsto p\restriction\varnothing=\{\phi\in p:\phi$ is a formula over $\varnothing\}$ and showing that $f(p)$ is isolated, but I can't seem to make that work either.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or should I just be approaching the problem in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The restriction map $S_n(A)\to S_n(\varnothing)$ is surjective.